# My DVD installer has been loading for 20 mins

Tags: livedvd

I have downloaded your DVD image. I have burnt it on a regular dvd.

But it has been loading for 20 minutes already. I've installed Ubuntu on 5 computers at least, and this is the first time I face this problem.

The probable cause of this problem is that I was using Windows 8 to burn the image. If that's the problem, I'il just burn the image again at low speed using cdburner xp.

Thanks,
Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

Test your media for errors on boot, before loading the installation. It seems to be a read error.